# PDF generated by Shopware 6 is not working in Acrobat Reader

Tags: adobe-reader

We generate Invoices in a Shopware 6 shop which display fine in Chrome & Firefox & Ubuntu's PDF viewer but not in Acrobat Reader.

```
file test.pdf
PDF document, version 1.7, 0 pages
```

The PDF should have logo and positions, but in Acrobat it displays only a small part:

[image: Screenshot]

How can this be debugged? Are there tools to validate a PDF further?

EDIT: I ran `pdfchecker` from https://www.datalogics.com/repair-pdf-files/ - I do not spot any obvious errors there?

The part

```
       Uses fonts that do not allow text to be extracted:
            SUBAAB+匀漀甀爀挀攀匀愀渀猀倀爀漀ⴀ刀攀最甀氀愀爀, SubType: Type0 (1 instance)
            SUBAAC+匀漀甀爀挀攀匀愀渀猀倀爀漀ⴀ䈀漀氀搀, SubType: Type0 (1 instance)
```

looks strange, as we don't use Chinese in the document. Also the missing parts are not only fonts but also a logo.

Full output:

```
$ ./pdfchecker -i example.pdf -j CheckerProfiles/everything.json 
PDF Checker 2.2.0  Copyright 2018-2021 Datalogics, Inc. All Rights Reserved

PDF Checker 2.2.0  Copyright 2018-2021 Datalogics, Inc. All Rights Reserved

Wed May 10 07:56:53 2023

JSON Profile: CheckerProfiles/everything.json

Input Document: example.pdf

Number of Pages: 1

Language: None

PDF Version: 1.7

Author: 
Creation Date: 2023-May-05 09:04:03
Creator: 
Keywords: 
Modification Date: 2023-May-05 09:04:03
Producer: dompdf 1.0.3 + CPDF
Subject: 
Title: Rechnungs-Nr. 41292
Trapped: 

File Size: 38.3 KB

<<=CHECKER_SUMMARY_START=>>
general:born-digital
userdata:contains-transparency
fonts:found-non-extractible-text
cleanup:suboptimal-compression
images:color:resolution-too-low
images:grayscale:resolution-too-low
sizeInBytes:39219
canBeOptimized
<<=CHECKER_SUMMARY_END=>>

Optimization Assessment
    Document can be optimized with PDF Optimizer - see details below

General Results
    Errors:
        None
    Information:
        Document was born digital.  It was produced from PDF authoring software and so it may contain text, images, tables, forms, and other objects.  These types of PDFs typically do not require OCR.
    Checks Completed:
        acroforms-type
        born-digital
        claims-pdfe-conformance
        claims-pdfua-conformance
        claims-pdfvt-conformance
        claims-pdfx-conformance
        contains-owner-password
        contains-signature
        damaged
        does-not-conform-to-claimed-pdfa-type
        image-only
        password-protected
        pdf-v2
        tagged-pdf
        unable-to-open
        xfa-type

Userdata Results
    Errors:
        None
    Information:
        Contains transparency:
            Total: (1 instance)
    Checks Completed:
        contains-annots
        contains-annots-not-for-printing
        contains-annots-not-for-viewing
        contains-annots-without-normal-appearances
        contains-embedded-files
        contains-metadata
        contains-optional-content
        contains-private-data
        contains-transparency
    How To Optimize:
        Transparency (which is not universally supported by PDF Viewers) can be flattened using PDF Optimizer. (1 instance)

Fonts Results
    Errors:
        None
    Information:
        Uses fonts that do not allow text to be extracted:
            SUBAAB+匀漀甀爀挀攀匀愀渀猀倀爀漀ⴀ刀攀最甀氀愀爀, SubType: Type0 (1 instance)
            SUBAAC+匀漀甀爀挀攀匀愀渀猀倀爀漀ⴀ䈀漀氀搀, SubType: Type0 (1 instance)
    Checks Completed:
        fontdescriptor-missing-capheight
        fontdescriptor-missing-fields
        found-non-extractible-text
        uses-base14fonts-not-embedded
        uses-fonts-fully-embedded
        uses-fonts-not-embedded

Objects Results
    Errors:
        None
    Information:
        None
    Checks Completed:
        contains-javascript-actions
        contains-thumbnails

Cleanup Results
    Errors:
        None
    Information:
        Contains conservatively compressed streams:
            Uncompressed: (2 instances)
    Checks Completed:
        suboptimal-compression

Image Results
    Errors:
        None
    Information:
        None
    Checks Completed:
        alternate-images

    Color Images
    Errors:
        None
    Information:
        Low resolution color image(s) present:
            Total: (1 instance)
    Checks Completed:
        image-depth
        resolution-too-high
        resolution-too-low
        uses-jpeg2000-compression

    Grayscale Images
    Errors:
        None
    Information:
        Low resolution gray image(s) present:
            Total: (1 instance)
    Checks Completed:
        resolution-too-high
        resolution-too-low
        uses-jpeg2000-compression

    Monochrome Images
    Errors:
        None
    Information:
        None
    Checks Completed:
        resolution-too-high
        resolution-too-low
        uses-jbig2-compression
```

EDIT2:
We still were not able to produce a PDF to share. That is because this happens only on production. It does not even happen on staging which is just another web root in the same server.

My colleague found out, that source_sans_pro_normal.ufm.php file differs - we try to track down out, how this could happen.

[image: DomPDF Font Difference]

https://github.com/shopwareLabs/dompdf/tree/d33e0741155134ffd2bffffcc3fdec7c7b5a67ba/lib/fonts does not contain those `.php` files - the seem to be [generated here](https://github.com/shopwareLabs/dompdf/blob/d33e0741155134ffd2bffffcc3fdec7c7b5a67ba/lib/Cpdf.php#L3313).

Comment: You could try to generate a test Document (without giving out Private Data) which you can upload here. It may be easier to Debug the Issue when that is given.

Comment: Good idea, will try.

Comment: It's not so easy .. but we'll still try - do you know any tools to analyze that we could run on our PDF and post the output?

Comment: (1) I have come across many Online Document Checking tools , which require uploading the Document , though that is **Essentially** Same as uploading the Document to your Post here. [[ Continued ]]

Comment: [[ Continued ]] (2) Example tools are : (A) https://helpx.adobe.com/in/acrobat/using/create-verify-pdf-accessibility.html (B) https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2020/pdf-inspector/ (C) https://www.datalogics.com/repair-pdf-files/ ....

Comment: Cool, thanks, updated my question with the tool in (C)

Answer (score 1):

I had suggested 3 tools & you have used 1 of those tools , which is throwing some light on the Issue.

The Output from that tool shows :

```
...  
...  
    Color Images  
    Information:  
        Low resolution color image(s) present:  
    Grayscale Images  
    Information:  
        Low resolution gray image(s) present:  
...  
...
```

These Images are not Displaying Properly by Adobe ( A Common Compliant online ! ) due to low DPI resolution.

Solution :

(A) You should increase the DPI resolution (1) When generating the Original Images & (2) When inserting/embedding into the Document & (3) When generating the Document.

(B) You should look into Web-View & Print Quality Settings concerning DPI resolution.

(C) You could try getting output from the 2 other tools too , which may throw more light on the Issue.

Comment: I think i cannot access (A) because it needs a adobe account / adobe pro ? and (B) because it needs a mac?
We will try to make a reproducible example - which will take some time :-) Thank you so far! :)

Actually not only the logo is missing, also the invoice positions.

Comment: We can make more Progress when we have Example Document , otherwise we can only give "Common/general Case" Comments. I hope you are able to make the Document without Private Data , to upload here.

Comment: We cannot reproduce locally yet, which makes us believe the problem is related to the Ubuntu production server. Still trying...

Answer (score 0):

We "fixed" this by copying the `vendor/shopwarelabs/dompdf` over to production from a system where the files are not corrupt.